# How to get only stdout_lines with Ansible using mail module

Tags: linux, email, ansible, clamav, module

I'm using ansible to scan hosts with clam antivirus and I'm receiving reports via email.
Reports contain everything and I want only to receive stdout lines.
Is there any way to accomplish this?
I wrote email template according to https://gist.github.com/halberom/0aea275632d2b47af0536e5def01d4d2
although only thing that is not the same is that I've piped to nice json:

```
The {{ host }} says {{ hostvars[host]['result']['stdout'] | to_nice_json }}
```

The error I get is:

> Unable to convert data using to_nice_json, falling back to to_json: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'. the task includes an option with an undefined variable the error was ansible no_log:false

If I remove `['stdout']` then email report looks like this:

```
ClamAV scan was performed on host_server
{
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": [
                "clamscan",
                "-r",
                "-i",
                "/usr/bin"
            ],
            "delta": "0:00:37.293719",
            "end": "2021-09-09 18:47:55.626094",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "clamscan -r -i /usr/bin",
                    "_uses_shell": false,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "stdin_add_newline": true,
                    "strip_empty_ends": true,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "/usr/bin",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2021-09-09 18:47:18.332375",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "\n----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------\nKnown viruses: 8563204\nEngine version: 0.103.2\nScanned directories: 1\nScanned files: 701\nInfected files: 0\nData scanned: 110.08 MB\nData read: 109.50 MB (ratio 1.01:1)\nTime: 37.113 sec (0 m 37 s)\nStart Date: 2021:09:09 18:47:18\nEnd Date:   2021:09:09 18:47:55",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "",
                "----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------",
                "Known viruses: 8563204",
                "Engine version: 0.103.2",
                "Scanned directories: 1",
                "Scanned files: 701",
                "Infected files: 0",
                "Data scanned: 110.08 MB",
                "Data read: 109.50 MB (ratio 1.01:1)",
                "Time: 37.113 sec (0 m 37 s)",
                "Start Date: 2021:09:09 18:47:18",
                "End Date: 2021:09:09 18:47:55 "
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish getting only stdout_lines in my report? I tried with grep in the shell command but failed

Answer (score 0):

From your debug, `result` is a registered var from a shell task where run `clamav` looping on a list of paths.

As described in the [ansible loop documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop), the registered var is modified to contain a `results` list where each element is an individual result from running the module with the current iterated item (e.g. `/usr/bin` in your example).

In this case, `result.stdout` does not exist (as clearly reported by your error message) but, as a specific example, `result.results.0.stdout` does exist in your example.

Although this would work if you always have a single path in your loop, you probaly want to get a list of all stdout from each result. In this case you can use:

```
result.results | map(attribute='stdout')
```

If we put this back into your specific template able to give an output for any given `host`, this would give:

```
The {{ host }} says {{ hostvars[host].result.results | map(attribute='stdout') | to_nice_json }}
```

Note that going to json here might not really be the best option for an email and that the above is loosing the info about the original path that was scanned. An alternate option might be to simply loop over the results and print out only the info you need:

```
This is report for host {{ host }}
----------------------------------
{% for scan_result in hostvars[host].result.results %}
Scan performed in directory {{ scan_result.item }}:
{{ scan_result.stdout }}
{% endfor %}
```